# Aucun accord du participe passé lorque l'objet est un pronom ?

Tags: grammaire, accord, infinitif, participe-passé, verbes-de-perception

Page 25 de *Advanced French Grammar*, V. Mazet écrit :

> With verbs of perception, if the pronoun is a replacement for the OBJECT, there's no agreement of the past participle. In the following example, **la vieille prison** does not demolish itself or anything else, it is being demolished. It is the object of démolir and there is no agreement.
>
> Nous avons vu démolir **la vieille prison**. = *We saw the old jail being demolished.*
>   Nous **l'** avons vu démolir. = *We saw it being demolished.*

1. Le pronom défini ici, est-il **la** ou **le** ?

   Du reste, pourquoi pas :

   1.a. Nous avons vu **la [ = la vieille prison ]** démolir ?

   1.b. Nous avons vu **démolir la vieille prison**. = Nous  **l(e)' [ = démolir la vieille prison ]** avons vu.
2. Quand un verbe ne s'appuie pas sur la perception (en termes de Mazet : "verbs of perception"), que se produira-t-il ? Prière de ne pas hésiter à fournir les exemples issus de la littérature. J'en sélectionne exprès une des plus prolixes pour m'y habituer.

   > Désirant empêcher , porte l'article 9 de cet édit, que, par un abus qui s'est introduit dans quelques provinces , les parens nominateurs ne cherchent à s'exempter du péril de la tutelle, en donnant leur suffrage à un sujet qu'ils prévoient ne pouvoir être nommé, voulons que ceux mêmes dont l'avis n'aura pas été suivi, demeurent responsables, ainsi qu'il sera dit ci-après , de la gestion du tuteur qui aura été nommé , si ce n'est qu'ils  aient interjeté appel de la sentence de tutelle, et **fait infirmer** ladite sentence; lequel appel ils seront tenus de relever en notre cour de parlement, trois mois au plus tard, à compter du jour de la sentence, sinon ils demeureront déchus de plein droit dudit appel , ou de » la faculté d'appeler ». [Source](http://books.google.com/books?id=TdpEAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA192&dq=%22fait+infirmer+ladite%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PyRqUqCdC6mpiAezjYGABQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22fait%20infirmer%20ladite%22&f=false)

Comment: Je ne comprends pas du tout ce que tu as voulu dire dans la question 2.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : Merci de votre avertissement. Je l'ai amendée; est-elle meilleure ?

Answer (score 2):

L'accord du participe suivi d'un infinitif est passablement complexe, particulièrement les kafkaïennes règles "traditionnelles" concernant l'accord de *laissé* suivi d'un infinitif. Personnellement, je me fais un plaisir de suivre la [nouvelle orthographe](http://www.orthographe-recommandee.info/regles10.htm) dans ce cas, qui traite tout bonnement le participe passé de *laisser* comme invariable (le verbe *faire* était déjà traité de la même manière, ce qui résout définitivement la question de l'accord dans ton deuxième exemple).

Dans le cas le plus simple, qui est celui appliqué par Mazet à ses "verbes de perception" probablement parce que ces verbes, après *laisser* et *faire* sont le cas de figure le plus commun, en plus de la règle habituelle concernant l'emplacement du complément relatif au verbe, **on accorde avec le complément d'objet du verbe composé *si et seulement si* ce complément est le sujet du verbe infinitif**. Édouard et cl-r ont décrit en détails comment faire cette détermination, et je ne m'y attarderai donc pas.

L'autre apparente exception [Grevisse, le bon usage, §951.b)3°] est celle **des verbe d'expression et d'opinion** (*savoir, considérer, dire, affirmer*...), dont les participes passés sont aussi invariables lorsque suivi d'un infinitif. Pour comprendre, comparons (nonobstant le fait que la première construction emploient plus naturellement un pronom que le nom) ces deux phrases:

> La femme que j'ai vue casser cette fenêtre.
>
> Des décisions qu'on a plus tard reconnu être des erreurs.

Si on le remets dans la construction de "départ":

> J'ai vu **cette femme** casser cette fenêtre.
>
> On a plus tard reconnu **que ces décisions étaient des erreurs**.

Il devient alors plus clair que le COD de *reconnaître* est en fait une proposition qui est devenue automatiquement infinitive lorsqu'on en a extrait le sujet.

Answer (score 1):

Prenons les phrases « J’ai vu démolir la vieille prison » ou « Je ferai livrer ce colis »<sup>1</sup>. Le verbe conjugué n’a pas d’objet et a pour complément un verbe à l’infinitif. Ledit verbe à l’infinitif possède, quant à lui, un complément d’objet. Si l’on désire remplacer ce complément d’objet par un pronom, celui-ci se placera devant le verbe conjugué.

> *J’ai vu démolir la vieille prison.*
> Je **l’**ai vu démolir.
>
> *Je ferai livrer ce colis.*
> Je **le** ferai livrer.

*« <strike>J’ai vu la démolir</strike> » ou *« <strike>Je ferai le livrer</strike> » n’est tout simplement pas correct.

Toutefois, *si le verbe conjugué a un complément d’objet* qui fait office de « sujet » du verbe à l’infinitf, alors on peut écrire :

> *J’ai vu l‘entreprise démolir la vieille prison.*
> J’ai vu l’entreprise **la** démolir.

ou

> Je l’ai vu démolir par l’entreprise.

Mais on ne pourra pas écrire :

> *<strike>Je l’ai vu l’entreprise démolir.</strike>

---

Une remarque : la phrase « Je l’ai vu démolir » est ambiguë. En effet, prenons les phrases « J’ai vu l’ouvrier démolir » et « J’ai vu l’entreprise démolir. » Alors, si l’on remplace « l’ouvrier » ou « l’entreprise » par des pronoms, on obtient :

> *J’ai vu l’ouvrier démolir.*
> Je **l’**ai vu démolir.
>
> *J’ai vu l’entreprise démolir.*
> Je **l’**ai vu**e** démolir.

On voit que, dans la phrase « Je l’ai vu démolir », le « l’ » peut se rapporter à ce qui démolit ou à ce qui *est* démoli, selon le contexte.

Remarquons que, dans le deuxième exemple, « l’entreprise » (ou « l’ ») est complément d’objet direct du verbe « ai vu » et exécute l’action « démolir ». Dans ce cas, le participe passé « vu » s’accorde en genre et en nombre avec son complément d’objet *lorsqu’il est placé devant*. Ce qui est bien le cas lorsque l’on emploie le pronom.

---

<sup>1</sup> L’extrait « article 9 » est inutilement compliqué et date du XVIII<sup>e</sup>, je l’évite volontairement.

Answer (score 0):

1. Le pronom est *la*, en accord avec le féminin de *la vieille prison*

   1.a. Le pronom doit se placer avant le verbe, *Nous avons vu la démolir* est donc incorrect. Cependant, si les acteurs de la démolition sont mentionnés, la forme *Nous avons vu les ouvriers la démolir* est alors la forme correcte.

   1.b. *Nous l'avons vu* veux alors dire *We saw it / We saw that*, et non *We saw it being demolished*.
2. Je ne comprends pas la question, désolé...

Comment: Merci de votre avertissement. J'ai amendé ma Q2; est-elle meilleure ?

Answer (score 0):

> - Nous *l*'avons vu démolir : **l'** renvoie à l'agent démolisseur.
> - Nous *l*'avons vu être démolie : **l'** renvoie à la prison, l'accord s'impose.

**et** *'fait infirmer'* est lié à *'Désirant empêcher'* par le *et*, dans une phrase à périodes multiples.

Il est difficile d'utiliser le point de vu grammatical pour comprendre une phrase 'périodique' ; la grammaire ne vient que confirmer la logique du texte que l'argumentaire juridique veut mettre en avant.

Comment: Dans « nous l’avons vu démolir », « l’ » peut tout à fait faire référence à « la prison » également. Il est cependant vrai que la phrase est ambiguë et que l’on comprendra bien plus vite « Nous avons vu untel démolir la maison ».

Comment: @Édouard Peut-être dans un contexte où **l'** ne peut faire référence qu'à la démolition elle-même, dans un dialogue familier ; sinon 1°) une maison ne se démolie pas toute seule (rappelé dans l'énoncée), elle s'effondre,  2°) elle peut démolir une autre bâtisse en s'effondrant ou en étant elle-même démolie : "nous l'avons vu démolir la cabane du jardinier quand le mur s'est effondré".

Comment: Dans un français pas familier pour deux sous, la position correcte du pronom qui se rapporte à « la vieille prison » est bien « Je l’ai vu démolir ». L’exemple de Mazet est tout à fait correct. La difficulté est que « Je l’ai vu démolir » peut signifier à la fois « J’ai vu [quelqu’un] démolir » ou « J’ai vu démolir [quelque chose] ».